# I am trying to add an additional If statement alongside an isblank statement. But i get a too many arguments message

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My current formula is:

=IF(AC52153<C52153,"PD","C")

the cells AC52153 and C52153 are dates

I have to add an additional if statement for when the cell AC52153 is blank to state "C"

So far I have come up with

=IF(AC52153<C52153,"PD","C" IF(ISBLANK(AC52153), "C")) but this gives me the error of too many arguments.

Comment: Did you mean
=IF(AC52153<C52153,"PD",IF(ISBLANK(AC52153), "C"))

Answer (score 1):

Try the below formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AC52153), "C",IF(AC52153<C52153,"PD","C" ))
```

Comment: It would be useful to explain _why_ this is the correct formula